# I'm having trouble getting categories and subcategories

Tags: php, sql, oop, function, recursion

Here's my database:

```
id         name       parent_id

1          Computers   NULL
2          Apple       1
3          Books       1
4          Music       NULL
5          CDs         4
6          Records     4
```

My categories function:

```
 public function showCategories($parent_id = 0){
        if($parent_id == 0){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL";
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id =:parentid";
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':parentid', $parent_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $categories = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            array_push($categories, array($row['id'] => $row['name']));
        }
        return $categories;
    }
```

Here's my category page:

```
<?php
//Instantiate categories class
$categories = new categories($db);
$categoriesMain = $categories->showCategories(0);
?>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <form action="" method="post">
           <?php //Get parent categories and put them into a select box ?>
           <select name="categoriesMain">
                <?php for($i=0;$i<count($categoriesMain);$i++){ ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                           <?php echo $categoriesMain[$i]; ?>
                      </option>
                <?php } ?>
           </select>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
       </form>

       <?php //if form submits then show sub categories ?>
          <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $categoriesSub = $categories->showCategories($_POST['categoriesMain']);
                    for($i=0;$i<count($categoriesSub);$i++){
                        echo $categoriesSub[$i];
                    }
          } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me try to explain what im having trouble with. I think my whole design is out of place because it feels like that but im having a brain block at the moment.

In the function I'm returning an array like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Computers ) [1] => Array ( [4] => Music ) )`. If you think this is the wrong way to return it let me know. Ok then do you see `CategoriesMain`? I'm using a for loop to output this array and for `option=value im echoing $i` however this $i goes like `1, 2, 3, 4` however I want the value to be the value of the parent category e.g. `1, 4` so that I can collect the value using `$_POST['cateogoriesMain']` in the next for loop where I'm displaying `cateogriesSub` where it will get the database rows for those with the `parent_id = to whatever was selected in the selectbox` previously. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the key of the array for the option value, like this:

```
   <select name="categoriesMain">
            <?php foreach ($categoriesMain as $k => $v) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>">
                       <?php echo $v; ?>
                  </option>
            <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

**edit** also change the following line inside the php function, instead of:

```
array_push($categories, array($row['id'] => $row['name']));
```

do

```
$categories[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
```